# c# nUnit, log mock verify doesn't work where is called for multiple time in the code

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-core-3.1, ilogger

I am working on .NET CORE 3.1 nUnit tests and trying to verify log. I have notice that log that call single time does recognize and work and if same log in loop for example `log.logDebug when record does not exist` does not work with verify code.

log is instance of ILogger mock

class

```
log.LogDebug("No files discovered in testing....");
```

Test

```
_loggerMoq.Verify(
            x => x.Log(
                LogLevel.Debug,
                It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((o, t) => string.Equals("No files discovered in testing....", o.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
                It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()),
            Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()),` to `(Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()),`

Not sure why this works, it is a known bug in the Moq library.

Answer (score 0):

```
_loggerMoq.Verify(
            x => x.Log(
                LogLevel.Debug,
                It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((o, t) => string.Equals("No files discovered in testing....", o.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
                It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()),
            Times.AtLeastOnce());
```